# Responsive/Bootstrap HTML - How to create awkward angled navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a secondary navigation at the top right corner of a site design. It is an awkward shape - 3 rectangles rotated - and all 3 need to be clickable.

It is a Twitter Bootstrap responsive site.

What is the best way to make them link? An image map seems too dated - chopping up 3 clickable images is awkward due to the angles involved. 3 Div's on top maybe? How can the DIV's keep correctly aligned with their targets whilst remaining responsive and working with Bootstrap?

UPDATE

The click areas need to stay in the top right over the image the whole time at every responsive width - including the mobile size.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `css-transform` to achieve what you are looking for.

Read the below for more details.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

Comment: very cool - what would be the suggestion for browsers that dont support that?

What about keeping it aligned? I have updated question.

Comment: this does seem a little experimental / early / risky to be using now perhaps?

Comment: Yes. It is a CSS3 property. - @niico